# Use google-speech-to-text with API key in frontend javascript

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I know it is a bad idea to have API key in frontend code,

And I know google-speech-to-text has free version with HTML5

But can I use google-speech-to-text with API key in html javascript?

Comment: _"And I know google-speech-to-text has free version with HTML5"_ Do you have a link for this?

Comment: @phuzi recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition() || new SpeechRecognition()

Comment: That isn't Google Speech to Text, but is the browser's [Web Speech API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API/Using_the_Web_Speech_API) that's built in to some browsers at varying levels of implementation/support. Check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=speech%20recognition) for browser support. This method doesn't require an API key but is very limited.

Comment: If you want to use the paid for Google Text to Speech you're going to need a backend that uses the Google Text to Speech SDK along with an API key. It really depends on what you're trying to do.